# Prove that a finitely generated $\mathbb F_p[t]$-module is a free $\mathbb F_p[t]$-module.

Tags: group-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules, graded-modules

Specifically, I am asked to show that if $(G,\omega)$ is a $p$-valued group of finite rank, (meaning that the associated graded group $grG$ is finitely generated as an $\mathbb F_p[t]$-module), then $grG$ is free as a graded $\mathbb F_p[t]$.

I am unsure what this question is actually asking me to do, because it sounds like it is asking me to prove the assumption?

Would it not be sufficient to just take the finite generating set, and then cast out any non-linearly independent terms, thereby giving us a set that the module is free on?

Any help clarifying the objective of this question would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ is a principal ideal domain, any module of finite rank on $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ is free if, and only if, it as no torsion. This is a classical result you should find on the Internet. So here tou have to show that $grG$ has no torsion

Comment: Adding to @AlexL a simple counterexample: Let $M=\mathbb{F}_p[t]/(t)\simeq\mathbb{F}_p$. It is a module over $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$. It is finitely generated because it is finite as a set. And by the same argument it is not free.